# How to make counter of input symbols using RxSwift?

Tags: swift, textview, counter, rx-swift

I have a TextView and I want to make a counter of input symbols with the help of RxSwift (ex. 1/1000, 2/1000 etc)

If you know how can I achieve this, please, help

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.rx.text
    .map { "\($0?.count ?? 0)/1000" }
    .bind(to: label.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, counter now is working, but maybe you know how to stop input when its 1000/1000?

Comment: Why don't you make an attempt and if you have trouble, then ask another question. Show what you have tried next time. (and mark this answer as correct.)